# Adding an InlineField to a ClusterableModel does not work

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I have a Page class called EventDetail which in turn holds several messages (to be sent out via a cronjob). This is done as shown in the docs here:
https://docs.wagtail.io/en/v2.5.1/reference/pages/panels.html?highlight=available%20panel%20types#inline-panels

The thing is that I also want to be able to append several files to each message. But now I am not on a Page class any more, and I cant get it to work. I read on other forum posts, that it is possible to to this by making the model that should hold the InlinePanel into a ClusterableModel, but I cant get it to work. When doing this I get the following when accessing the page:

```
FieldError at /admin/message/eventdetailmessage/create/
Unknown field(s) (files) specified for EventDetailMessage
```

My code:

```
class Message(models.Model):
"""
    An abstract model of messages connected to an eventdetail
"""

title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
content = models.TextField()
send_time = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_("Message send time"))
sent = models.BooleanField(default=False)

@property
def edit_link(self):
    return self.url_helper.get_action_url("edit", self.id)

@property
def delete_link(self):
    return self.url_helper.get_action_url("delete", self.id)

@property
def create_link(self):
    return f"{self.url_helper.get_action_url('create')}?id={self.event_detail.id}"

panels = [FieldPanel("title"), FieldPanel("content"), FieldPanel("send_time")]

class Meta:
    abstract = True

class EventDetailMessage(ClusterableModel, Orderable, Message):
"""
    The actual implementation. Done like this in case we want do use
    wagtails built in functionality for creating on the fly. 
"""

event_detail = ParentalKey(
    EventDetail, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="messages"
)

panels = [FieldPanel("event_detail"), InlinePanel("files")] + Message.panels

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    from .wagtail_hooks import MessageDataAdmin

    self.url_helper = MessageDataAdmin().url_helper
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title


class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    message = ParentalKey(
        EventDetailMessage, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="files"
    )

    panels = [FieldPanel("file")]
```

Comment: there is no `files` in defined in `EventDetailMessage`

Comment: @Alex It is, but via the related name on the File class. Our did I misunderstand something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it! The ParentalKey definition under the File class needs to be defined with quotes otherwise it doesnt work, it should be like this:

```
message = ParentalKey(
    "message.EventDetailMessage", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="files"
)
```

However Im still unsure why this is, can someone explain?